# aws sdk not working while building the library in angular7

Tags: angular7

BUILD ERROR

> node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http_response.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http_response.d.ts(14,18): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(132,37): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(134,38): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(468,32): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(470,32): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/apigateway.d.ts(1146,23): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/clouddirectory.d.ts(1573,38): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/cloudsearchdomain.d.ts(7,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
>
> node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/cloudsearchdomain.d.ts(42,23): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig.`enter code here`

Comment: tsconfig.json

{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [ "node" ],
"lib": [
"es2018",
"dom"
],
"paths": {
"common-registration": [
"dist/common-registration"
],
"common-registration/": [
"dist/common-registration/"
]
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
  "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
```

to you tsconfig.json object. and run your server. As illustrated below. It worked for me.

```
tsconfig.json { 
"compileOnSave": false, enter code here
  "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
"compilerOptions": 
{ "baseUrl": "./", 
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", 
"sourceMap": true, 
"declaration": false,
 "module": "es2015", 
"moduleResolution": "node", 
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
"experimentalDecorators": true, 
"importHelpers": true, 
"target": "es5", 
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], 
"types": [ "node" ], 
"lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ], 
"paths": { "common-registration": [ "dist/common-registration" ], 
"common-registration/": [ "dist/common-registration/" ] } } }
```